# Multithreading python (using _thread), doesn't do anything

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

First of all, here are my two python files:

sred.py:

```
import _thread,time

class Thread:

def __init__(self,time:int,say:str):

    self.time=time
    self.say=say


def create():
    id = _thread.get_ident() 


    for i in range(5):

        print("HALLO", id)

    return

from sred import Thread
import time,_thread

_thread.start_new_thread(Thread.create,())
```

The second one:
main.py

```
from sred import Thread
import time,_thread

_thread.start_new_thread(Thread.create,())
```

when executing this it doesn't print anything out, why?

UPDATE:

```
import _thread

class Thread:


    @classmethod
    def create():
        id = _thread.get_ident() 


        for i in range(5):
            print("HALLO", id)
        return
```

main.py:

```
from sred import Thread
import time,_thread

_thread.start_new_thread(Thread().create,())
```

Is this now right, or is there still something wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `_thread` and not `threading`?

Comment: it just was in my book, so I used it

Comment: `threading` is the high-level API, `_thread` is quite low-level (and as suggested by the leading underscore, is basically an implementation detail)

Comment: I will try to use threading, but do you know what I could have done wrong maybe?

Comment: What book says "import _thread"?

Comment: the German book "Einstieg in Python"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `create` method is missing `self` as a parameter -- it looks like it should also be a  `@classmethod` if you want to call it as it's written now. Note that your `__init__` method is never getting called, because you never instantiate any `Thread` objects. You may want it to read:

```
_thread.start_new_thread(Thread().create, ())
```

i.e., instantiate a thread, then pass its `create` method to be executed in the new thread. I'm not sure what's happening, but I suspect that something is erroring and the [stacktrace is being suppressed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/_thread.html#_thread.start_new_thread) by something.

Also, you need to delete the space after the `for` statement -- it's significant, and it should be throwing you a syntax error about an unexpected indent.

EDIT:

This version runs on my machine:

```
import _thread

class Thread:
    def create(self):
        id = _thread.get_ident() 

        for i in range(5):
            print("HALLO", id)
        return

_thread.start_new_thread(Thread().create, ())
```

Comment: Is the UPDATE what you meant?

Comment: `create` still needs `cls` as a parameter. Your code as written should be throwing a bunch of errors -- make sure you're copying it with the correct indentation and with no extra linebreaks.

Comment: I didn't get any errors, I also added cls now as a parameter and the output is still nothing.

Comment: Your code as written in this thread will not run because of problems with indentation. I can't tell which of those problems are a result of the way you pasted it, and which are actually in your code. Please fix the indentation in your post and make sure you've posted exactly what you're running.

Comment: I think I fixed the indentation now.

Comment: If you're calling it as `Thread().create`, `create` shouldn't be a classmethod. But it needs to have `self` as a parameter: `def create(self):...`. When I run your code on my machine, I get an error, you should be getting an error too.

Comment: are you using python3, because I'm not getting any errrors.

Comment: I also put self as the parameter, could you please copy the error?

Comment: I will try to fix everything what I copied here.

Comment: `Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method type.create of <class '__main__.Thread'>> TypeError: create() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what this error means.

Comment: I still get absolutley nothing, what could cause this?

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: I ran your scrip with    python3 sred.py

Comment: Are you in a shell? You should be inside of a cmd instance or a bash shell, in the directory of the script, then run `python3 sred.py`, assuming `sred.py` contains the code I posted above.

Comment: I'm using Arch Linux,and I am in the directory of the script.

Comment: Are you sure the indentation is correct? I'm running it with python3 on my machine with no problems.

Comment: Has Python ever output anything for you? Can you get it to throw errors by trying to run something that's not valid? Are you sure that `python3` points to the location of your Python interpreter?

Comment: No, python didn't output anything, I will try to get the errors.

Comment: When trying to produce an error, it only shows the one error I made on purpose.